# Issue with LookerStudio Connector: Datetime Fields Not Displaying Properly

Tags: looker-studio

I am developing a connector for LookerStudio by following the official Google tutorial available at Google LookerStudio Connector Tutorial.

While most aspects of the connector work seamlessly, I am encountering an issue with datetime fields. According to the LookerStudio Connector Documentation, datetime fields should be declared as type YEAR_MONTH_DAY_SECOND and delivered as YYYYMMDDHHMMSS strings.

Following documentation guidelines my getSchema() function declares datetime fields as follow:

```
var fields = cc.getFields(); 
fields
    .newDimension()
    .setId('dealCreated')
    .setName('Deal Created')
    .setType(types.YEAR_MONTH_DAY_SECOND);
```

and I am using the following code to transform UTC dates to locale timezone dates and apply the YYYYMMDDHHMMSS format:

```
// date: a UTC date in YY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss format (as received from the original data source I am building my connector for).

function toLocalDatetime(date){

  date = new Date(date.replace(/[' ']/g, 'T') + 'Z');
  
  var year = date.toLocaleString("default", { year: "numeric" });
  var month = date.toLocaleString("default", { month: "2-digit" });
  var day = date.toLocaleString("default", { day: "2-digit" });
  var hour = date.toLocaleString("default", { hourCycle: "h23", hour: "2-digit" });
  var minute = date.toLocaleString("default", { minute: "2-digit" });
  var second = date.toLocaleString("es-ES", { second: "2-digit" });

  //YYMMDDHHMMSS formatting
  return year + month.padStart(2,'0') + day.padStart(2,'0') + hour.padStart(2,'0') + minute.padStart(2,'0') + second.padStart(2,'0');
  
}
```

Despite adhering to these guidelines, when using my connector as a datasource for a LookerStudio report, all datetime-defined dimensions appear as null values.

What is the correct type declaration and value format I should use to ensure LookerStudio properly receives and displays datetime fields from my connector?

Oddly enough if I define datetime fields as just date fields and send values in YYYYMMDD format everything works as expected.

I have explored suggestions to declare datetime fields as type TEXT and then use LookerStudio functions like PARSE_DATETIME within the LookerStudio playground. However, I am seeking a solution that directly aligns with the recommended approach outlined in the documentation.

Any insights or guidance on resolving this datetime field issue would be greatly appreciated.